# Ubuntu 15.04 new install will not shut off

Tags: shutdown

So I made the switch to linux (from Windows) today. Everything went well enough, but when I select `shut down` or `suspend,` the computer does not actually turn off (though it does, as far as I can tell, end running processses). It either ends with a purple or black screen. Any advice?

Comment: have you tried running `sudo poweroff` from a terminal?

Comment: had the same issue - and tried even Fedora and again no shutdown. It must be related to kernel. New versions have some bug about it. As long as you are a newbie, better to use LTS versions. Try Ubuntu 14.04. IT doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I have tried `sudo poweroff`, with the same result. And I started with 14.04. Upgraded to 15.04 in hopes that the bug had been fixed.

Comment: When you run `sudo poweroff` you can press F2 to see a verbose output where you should see where the system is getting hungup. Please post any relevant info as this info can really help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: Pressing F2 did not bring up any information?

Comment: This seems to be a larger problem than what I though. See different post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/639940/will-not-boot-normally-or-into-recovery

Comment: I have the same problem.